# Is fluorine also hybridised in carbon tetrafluoride?

Tags: bond, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, hybridization

I had read that when an atom forms multiple bonds, it hybridises it's orbitals to minimise the repulsion and decrease the overall energy. But do the terminal atoms also exist in hybridised form?

E.g. in $\ce{CF4}$, are fluorine orbitals also $sp^3$ hybridised, or maybe has some other type of hybridization, or no hybridization at all?

Also in a molecules like say $\ce{HF}$, in this case is $\ce{F}$ hybridised or not?

Comment: Hybridisation is a mathematical concept, you can use it or not, it does not make a difference. It cannot be measured. Please also note that atoms cannot be hybridised, only orbitals can. It is more than sloppy to say that 'F is hybridised'.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン In other words, you mark «F is hybridised» with a F.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Hybridised orbitals do exist in NBO calculations, which is essentially VB theory but more perfect.

Comment: I see that you keep commenting things like "not to use hybridisation for TM complexes" which is only useful for properties depending on the canonical MO's, e.g. the energies(ionisation, transition etc). Hybridisation is perfectly OK for intuitive things- go calculate some chromium carbonyl's NBO's.

Comment: @KanghunKim While indeed, NBO localises orbitals to be interpreted as hybrid orbitals, it's in no way as complete as VB theory; and especially it is not more perfect. It is an interpretation of a wave function, nothing more. It's fairly obvious that it has a lot of benefits, but it cannot provide a complete picture. Also, if you take the time to read the comments you refer to on the TM complexes, they always refer to the central atom. Go ahead and run the calculations, I very much doubt you'll find hybrid NBO on chromium. Except of course you're using a really old version.

Answer (score -2):

No Fluorine is not hybridised because every atom of Fluorine in CF4 make one bond which is the typical according to the octet rule.

Answer (score -2):

No, Flourine does not undergo hybridisation generally. In Carbon tetraflouride, there is a sigma bond formed by sp³- 2p orbital. Same applies for carbon tetrachloride and bromomethane.(atleast from exam's point of view) lone pair electrons of Flourine is in s and p orbitals.